# Using Azure PowerShell to add PIP to a VM and failed with The public IP name 104.40.63.116 is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have been using the following command to add a PIP to a VM without problem until today.

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "test1vm1" -Name "test1vm1" |  Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName "104.40.63.116" |  Update-AzureVM
```

On the Azure portal, I have created a VM (test1vm1) in a VNet (test1), and it is up and running.  On the portal, the VM (test1vm1) has

```
      PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS
          104.40.63.116
```

When I use Azure PowerShell to add the PIP using the above command, I got the following error:

```
VERBOSE: 10:35:07 AM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 10:35:08 AM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 10:35:08 AM - Begin Operation: Update-AzureVM

Update-AzureVM : BadRequest: The public IP name 104.40.63.116 is not valid.

At line:1 char:106

+ ... 4.40.63.116" | Update-AzureVM

+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureVM], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.UpdateAzureVMCommand
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign the IP directly to the VM like that.  You must first create a reserved IP in Azure and then use the "name" you associate with the IP in the Set-AzurePublicIP call.  For example:

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyIPAddress" –Location "West US"
```

This will reserve an IP (you can't specify which IP is reserved but it will be associated with the Azure Region you specify). Then use the "Name" as follows.

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName CloudServiceName -Name VirtualMachieName | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName MyIPAddress | Update-AzureVM
```

See that I pass in the "MyIPAddress" and no an actual IP address.

The public IP you see (VIP) is the Azure-issued IP that can change on host restart and isn't something you can explicitly reserve.